# Gradle `tasks.withType()` strange behavior for tasks added afterwards

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using Gradle 2.14.1 and the https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-testsets-plugin to add an integration test task. I would like to configures the location of the HTML reports.
The default tasks uses:

```
<project>/build/reports/tests
```

The testsets plugin configures:

```
<project>/build/intTest
```

for the `intTest` task, and I want:

```
<project>/build/reports/test
<project>/build/reports/intTest
```

Here is my configuration:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.unbroken-dome.gradle-plugins:gradle-testsets-plugin:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets'

defaultTasks = ['clean', 'build']

tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = new File(project.reportsDir, name)

    println(it.name + '\t' + reports.html.destination)
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    description = 'Defines the common gradle distribution for this project.'
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}

testSets {
    intTest
}

intTest.dependsOn test
check.dependsOn intTest

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    intTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

println('===== final config =====')
println(test.name + '\t' + test.reports.html.destination)
println(intTest.name + '\t' + intTest.reports.html.destination)
```

(Please ignore the `println` statements for the time being.)

After a full build, the `intTest` task's reports are in the wrong place (the default), and the configuration for the standard `test` task is applied:

```
$ ls build/
classes  dependency-cache  intTest  intTest-results  libs  reports  test-results  tmp

$ ls build/reports/
test
```

I added some output to see what is going on, and it seems strange (the project's root is 'blob'):

```
test    /home/wujek/blob/build/reports/test
intTest /home/wujek/blob/build/reports/intTest
===== final config =====
test    /home/wujek/blob/build/reports/test
intTest /home/wujek/blob/build/intTest
```

So, in the `tasks.withType()` block the location is reported to be correct, but in the end, it is not.

Please note that moving the `tasks.withType()` block after the `testSets` block works for this project, but my real setup is mode complex: I have mutliple modules, and the root `build.gradle` uses the `subprojects` block with the `tasks.withType()` block to configure the report locations for all modules, and then one of the submodules adds a new test set and its test task's HTML report has the wrong location. To fix this, I have to repeat the configuration in the submodules that add test sets.

What is going on here? Why does the `tasks.withType()` block say the config works, but in reality it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the pecularities of ordering configuration in Gradle. Let's walk through your code as Gradle would process it to see what happens (skipping over lines that aren't relevant):

```
apply plugin: 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets'
```

This executes the apply method of the test-sets plugin, which includes [the creation of a class which listens for test sets to be added](https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-testsets-plugin/blob/080f58ddbcb8aa589912562fe62973e3595fe718/src/main/groovy/org/unbrokendome/gradle/plugins/testsets/TestSetsPlugin.groovy#L30). [It adds a `whenObjectAdded` action](https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-testsets-plugin/blob/a6c528ade5198b2732719be20de0e46648228a2f/src/main/groovy/org/unbrokendome/gradle/plugins/testsets/internal/TestTaskListener.groovy#L19) to the `testSets` container. You haven't added any test sets yet, so lets move back to your `build.gradle`.

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = new File(project.reportsDir, name)

    println(it.name + '\t' + reports.html.destination)
}
```

You've now added an action that will apply to all existing `Test` tasks, and to new ones as they are created. Now where it all unwinds:

```
testSets {
    intTest
}
```

This creates a `testSet` called `intTest`. The `whenObjectAdded` action in the test-sets plugin now fires:

1. The `intTest` sets Test task [is created](https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-testsets-plugin/blob/a6c528ade5198b2732719be20de0e46648228a2f/src/main/groovy/org/unbrokendome/gradle/plugins/testsets/internal/TestTaskListener.groovy#L24).
2. Your `withType` action fires, because there's now a new `Test` task. This sets the report to go where you want.
3. The `whenObjectAdded` action now continues, getting to [this line](https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-testsets-plugin/blob/a6c528ade5198b2732719be20de0e46648228a2f/src/main/groovy/org/unbrokendome/gradle/plugins/testsets/internal/TestTaskListener.groovy#L42) which also sets the html report location, overriding what you just set.

When you change this to declare the `testSet` first it goes:

1. `whenObjectAdded` - Create the Test task
2. `whenObjectAdded` - Set the test task's HTML report location
3. `withType` is registered by you
4. `withType` fires setting the HTML report location to your desired destination

There aren't hard and fast rules to avoid this, since plugins can and do take wildly different approaches to how/when they register their configuration actions. Generally, I try to break my build.gradle down in this order:

1. Buildscript block (if needed)
2. apply plugins
3. set project level properties (group, version, sourceCompatibility, etc)
4. Configure extensions (sourceSets, testSets, configurations, dependencies)
5. Configure tasks (either direct or withType)

Usually this helps allow plugins that fire config to register default values before my configuration comes in to change things.

FYI, [Gradle's new, and still incubating, model space](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/software_model.html) is intended to help solve this configuration ordering problem. It won't be perfect, but allows the order to be more explicit.

Comment: Based on your explanation I was able to fix my issue. My setup is: I had the testSets plugin and the withType() block in the main build.gradle's subprojects block; the testSets { intTest } block is added in a submodule, which is evaluated only after that (hence the wrong config). So, to have the ordering as you suggest, I added the afterEvaluate {} block in the subprojects{} block and all the tasks.withType calls are there. Seems to work and it also makes sense: after all the subprojects are evaluated (their plugins added tasks etc.) the main build configures them centrally.

Comment: Yeah you're a little more limited in that case and I think afterEvaluate is probably your best option.